# How to prevent mocking of a class in mockito 3.x?

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

In mockito 1 we could have made a class final  with static methods to not prevent mocking. Now as mentioned in mockito [doc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.7.7/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) `mockito-inline` allows mocking of final and static methods.

Can someone let me know if there is a way to prevent mocking of a class in mockito 3.x?

Comment: Mocking is a tool, why do you want to prevent a tool from working?

Comment: What are trying to do and why do you want to control what developers are doing? lol
Anyway, if you need to mock but want to restrict it, you don't have the architecture of your ambitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned off by default:

"This mock maker is turned off by default because it is based on completely different mocking mechanism that requires more feedback from the community. It can be activated explicitly by the mockito extension mechanism, just create in the classpath a file /mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing the value mock-maker-inline."

According to: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.7.7/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39